# Extract two names from a string

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In Excel, assume

```
A2 = Last_Name1 First_Name1 MI1;#8;#Last_Name2 First_Name2 MI2;#102
```

In B2, I want to see the last name, first name and middle initial of the first person listed.  So I use this:

```
=MID(A2,1,FIND(";",A2,1)-1)
```

Result: Last_Name1 First_Name1 MI1

In C2, what do I need to write to see the last name, first name and middle initial of the second person listed.

Result: Last_Name2 First_Name2 MI2

My thought is to start from the right and get everything between the second "#" and ";" (#Last_Name2 First_Name2 MI2;).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Find the second ";" and start mid from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell C2, enter this formula:

```
=LEFT(MID(A2,2+FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,";","|",2)),99),LEN(MID(A2,2+FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,";","|",2)),99))-5)
```

Because of @pnuts notion, I think this version is even better

```
=LEFT(MID(A2,1+FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"#","|",2)),99),FIND(";",MID(A2,1+FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"#","|",2)),99))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(MID(A2,1+FIND("#",A2)+FIND("#",MID(A2,FIND("#",A2)+1,99)),99),FIND(";",MID(A2,1+FIND("#",A2)+FIND("#",MID(A2,FIND("#",A2)+1,99)),99))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This work in all situations (i.e. regardless of the length of the Last & First Names combination):

```
=MID(LEFT($A2,
-1+FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,";","|",3))),
1+FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"#","|",2)),LEN($A2))
```